# Are there statistics on the overall Area51/Stackexchange network?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Perhaps graphs of how many users/pageviews the network in general is getting? How many proposals make it to beta status, how many are closed, how many graduate...?

How well is StackExchange doing, as a whole?